# Retornar apenas resultados positivos

Tags: portugol, visualg

Estou fazendo um exercício no visualg, no qual o resultado pode ser tanto negativo como positivo, só que quero os resultado apenas positivos e não negativos. Como conseguir isso? O que tenho até agora:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 03/01/2018
// Seção de Declarações 
var
   time1,time2,dife:inteiro

inicio
      escreva("quantos gols do time A? ")
      leia(time1)
      escreva("quantos gols do time B? ")
      leia(time2)
      dife <- (time1 - time2)
      as <- (dife p ou q)
      se (dife >=1) e (dife <=3)
        escreva("partida normal", dife)
      senao
           se (dife =0) entao
             escreva(normal)
           FimSe
      FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize uma **[condicional](https://pt.slideshare.net/wbezerra/log-07-condicional)** antes de subtrair os valores da variável `time1` e `time2`:

```
se (time1 >= 0) e (time2 >= 0) entao
   /* Restante do código */
fimse
```

Faz anos que usei o `Portugol`, talvez tenha mudado alguma coisa, mas a lógica é a mesma.

Answer (score -1):

Olá tente fazer assim (precisa comparar qual é o maior antes de fazer a diferença):

```
algoritmo "exercicios"
var
time1,time2,dife:inteiro

  inicio
  escreva("quantos gols do time A? ")
  leia(time1)
  escreva("quantos gols do time B? ")
  leia(time2)
  se time1>=0 e time2>=0 entao
  se time1>time2 entao
  dife <- (time1 - time2)
  fimse
  fimse
  se time1>=0 e time2>=0 entao
  se time2>time1 entao
  dife<- time2-time1
  fimse
  fimse
  as <- (dife p ou q)
  se (dife >=1) e (dife <=3)
    escreva("partida normal", dife)
  senao
       se (dife =0) entao
         escreva(normal)
       fimse
   fimse
   fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score -1):

É possível utilizar a função `Abs` que retorna um número Absoluto, ou seja, sempre positivo.

Aqui um exemplo prático:

```
    algoritmo "BANGUxMADUREIRA"
    // Data : 29/05/2021
    // Seção de Declarações
    var
    ban, mad, dif: Inteiro
    
    inicio
    // Seção de Comandos
    escreval(" BANGU x MADUREIRA ")
    escreval("-------------------------------")
    escreva("QUANTOS GOLS DO BANGU? ")
    leia(ban)
    escreva("QUANTOS GOLS DO MADUREIRA? ")
    leia(mad)
    escreval("-------------------------------")
    dif <- abs(ban - mad)
    se (dif = 0) entao
       escreval(" DFERENÇA: ", dif)
       escreval(" STATUS: JOGO EMPATADO!")
       escreval("-------------------------------")
    senao
       se (dif = 1) entao
          escreval(" DFERENÇA: ", dif)
          escreval(" STATUS: JOGO ACIRRADO!")
          escreval("-------------------------------")
       senao
          se (dif >= 2) entao
             escreval(" DFERENÇA: ", dif)
             escreval(" STATUS: GOLEADA!")
             escreval("-------------------------------")
          senao
          fimse
       fimse
    fimse
    fimalgoritmo
```